# istgame: having trouble replicating a sketch of a game tree

Tags: overleaf, game-tree, istgame

I have been using the istgame package to construct a game tree. Here is what I am trying to replicate in LateX:

[image]

I have been able to make some progress on this, but it is still not where I would like things to be. Specifically, the parts where (1) the dictator selects either s = 0 or s > 0 and (2) opposition co-optation. I also feel like the tree could be constructed to look a bit smoother and more cohesive or elegant. Here is my attempt. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vpay{ m }
{\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}}

\begin{center}
    \begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
    \cntmAistb{w_L}[l]{w_H}[r]
        \istrootcntmA(0)(0,0){Nature} \istbA{}[r] \endist
        \istrootcntmA(1)([yshift=-1.5em]0-1){Dictator} \istbA{\gamma}[r] \endist
        \cntmAInfosetO[fill=blue!20](1)
        \cntmAistb{s = 0}[l]{s > 0}[r]
        \istrootcntmA(2)([yshift=-1.5em]1-1){Dictator} \istbA{}[r] \endist
        \cntmAInfosetO[fill=blue!20](2)
\xtdistance{7mm}{15mm}
\istroot(2a)([yshift=-1.5em]2-1){Opposition \\ (Cooperation)}
\istb{Comply}[al]{\vpay{(\gamma_i^\alpha-\gamma_i\theta)^2)\\\ \theta^2(1-\gamma_i)^2}}
\istb{Revolt}[ar]{\vpay{t_i\\\ z_i}}
\endist
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to draw the picture of the question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\vpay{ m }
{\begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\vplayer{ m }
{\makecell{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]

\cntmdistance{16mm}{40mm}
\xtdistance{30mm}{20mm}
\cntmApreset{.6}
\istrootcntmA(0){N}
  \istbA*(2){w_{i-1}}[left,near end]
  \istbA*(2){w_i}[right,near end]
  \istbA*(2){w_{iH}}[right,near end]
  \endist
\xtInfosetO([xshift=-5em]0-1)([xshift=5em]0-3){Dictator}[right,near end]

\istrootcntmA(1)(0-2)
  \istbA(2)
  \endist
\xtInfosetO([xshift=-8em]1-1)([xshift=8em]1-1){Dictator}[right,near end]

% trick : cntmA
\istrootcntmA(2)(1-1)
  \endist    
% trick A : s=0
\xtdistance{24mm}{60mm}
\istroot(2a)(1-1)
  \istb{s=0}[left,near end]
  \istbm
  \endist
% trick B : s>0
\xtdistance{24mm}{20mm}
\istroot(2b)(1-1)
  \istbA(.67)
  \istb{s>0}[right,near end]
  \endist

\istroot(3a)(2a-1)<180>{\vplayer{(Cooperation)\\Oppos.}}
  \istb*{comply}[l]
       {\vpay{(\gamma_i^\alpha-\gamma_i\theta)^2 \\ -\theta^2(1-\gamma_i)^2}}
  \istb{revolt}[r]
       {\vpay{t_i\\z_i}}
  \endist
\istroot(3b)(2b-2)<0>{\vplayer{(Cooptation)\\Opp}}
  \istb{revolt}[l]
       {\vpay{t_i\\z_i}}
  \istb*{comply}[r]
       {\vpay{(1-s_i)\gamma_i^\alpha-(\gamma_i\theta)^2 \\ 
        s_i\gamma_i^\alpha-\theta^2(1-\gamma_i)^2}}
  \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```